SQL join that excludes rows that have a shared value with another row
Please refer to this db fiddle (SQL also pasted below):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bJ5FfufvP9GHPYtBhkywdP/5
I would like to show rows from the "mpr_metrics" table that have NO associated reviews. But here's the catch: if there is a metric with an associated review, AND that review also shares the SAME start time as another review, then it should be excluded from the result set.
For example, the result of the fiddle is "3", but it should only show a count of "1", since there is only 1 metric (id=5) which has no review AND no review with the same start_time value as another review.
CREATE TABLE mpr_metrics (
  id INT,
  start_time TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE mpr_metrics_reviews (
  id INT,
  metric_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO mpr_metrics (id, start_time) values (1, '2024-09-16');
INSERT INTO mpr_metrics (id, start_time) values (2, '2024-09-16');
INSERT INTO mpr_metrics (id, start_time) values (3, '2024-09-09');
INSERT INTO mpr_metrics (id, start_time) values (4, '2024-09-09');
INSERT INTO mpr_metrics (id, start_time) values (5, '2024-09-11');

INSERT INTO mpr_metrics_reviews (id, metric_id) values (1, 1);
INSERT INTO mpr_metrics_reviews (id, metric_id) values (2, 3);

SELECT count(DISTINCT mpr_metrics.start_time) 
FROM mpr_metrics 
LEFT JOIN mpr_metrics_reviews 
    ON mpr_metrics.id = mpr_metrics_reviews.metric_id 
WHERE mpr_metrics_reviews.id is null;

The result of this SELECT is "3", but the result should be "1".

I'm getting confused. Twice you mention a review's start time, but reviews don't have start times in your data model. Metrics do. So, do you want all metrics that have no review and at the same time have a start time different from that of all other metrics?

Sample data and the fiddle is great, but can you also specify the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

@ThorstenKettner you're correct I meant to say metric start time, not review start time. Question is updated.

@jarlh They said the expected result is 1 instead of 3.

Updated tags, since the fiddle is 5.7. But are you really still using 5.7? You know it's been effectively abandonware for that past year, right? With no updates at all... not even critical security patches! It also hasn't really qualified as a modern database engine since around 2016; by that time other options had all added CTEs, window functions, lateral joins, etc.

it looks like there are a lot of potential answers already, which is amazing! Can anyone give me a sense of which of the below answers might be the most performant?

Care about performance when getting performance issues. Until then, just keep your queries as readable (and thus maintainable) as possible. At last, it is usually not the query that you'll tweak to get better performance. Most often it is just indexes you'll add to your database instead.

@DarrenGates Simply try out rather than let people guess who don't have access to your system. Keep in mind performance depends on data and infrastructure. Using such an old version of the RDBMS will likely not help to observe a good performance.

@ThorstenKettner True, and furthermore, often people don't know or forget that the optimizer mostly doesn't execute the query they write. It executes the most performant version of the provided query it can find. Meaning similar queries will often result in the absolute identic query that will really be executed by the RDBMS.

Why that anti join trick? Do you think that MySQL is not capable of running straight-forward NOT IN and NOT EXISTS in a reasonable time? This may have been the case in the very early days of the DBMS, but those days are gone.
You want two NOT EXISTS clauses, because you want metrics ...

... that have no reviews
... that have no start time siblings

The simple query:
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM mpr_metrics m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM mpr_metrics_reviews mr
                  WHERE mr.metric_id = m.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM mpr_metrics m2
                  WHERE m2.id <> m.id AND m2.start_time = m.start_time)
;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/kghxWWSh
(The first condition can easily be re-written as NOT IN, which may even be slightly more readable. While the second condition could also be converted into NOT IN, though, I suggest you stick to NOT EXISTS, because the IN clause would be correlated, and we strive to keep [NOT] IN clauses non-correlated for readability.)

The second NOT ESISTS is just checking metrics, not reviews.

Has MySQL really improved the optimization of IN/NOT IN and correlated subqueries? I've always shied away from them. Admittedly, we're still stuck on MySQL 5.5-5.7 in my shop.

Comment #1: Correct. Reviews don't have start times. The request has this mixed up. When I asked for clarification they said I was right that this is about metrics. They also tried to fix the explanation in the request, but they still have it mixed up. Comment #2: I am not a MySQL developer, but years ago I was told that IN clauses were no longer the problem they once had been.

Reviews have start times by linking them back to the metric via the metric_id foreign key.

You need another join to exclude rows that have shared start times with another row.
SELECT COUNT(distinct m.id) AS count
FROM mpr_metrics AS m
LEFT JOIN mpr_metrics_reviews AS r
    ON m.id = r.metric_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT m.id, m.start_time
  FROM mpr_metrics AS m
  JOIN mpr_metrics_reviews AS r
  ON m.id = r.metric_id
) AS m1 
    ON m.start_time = m1.start_time
WHERE r.id IS NULL and m1.id IS NULL


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mpr_metrics m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM mpr_metrics_reviews r
  WHERE r.metric_id = m.id
)
AND m.start_time NOT IN (
  SELECT m2.start_time
  FROM mpr_metrics m2
  INNER JOIN mpr_metrics_reviews r2 ON m2.id = r2.metric_id
);


NOT EXISTS: Metric has no associated reviews.
NOT IN: start_time of metric does not match a start_time of metrics that do have reviews


You can do something simple like this:
select count(id) from mpr_metrics where start_time not in (
     select distinct start_time from mpr_metrics where id in (select metric_id from mpr_metrics_reviews)
);

If the data set is large it would make sense to have an index on the start_time.
Updated db fiddle here
